# 現在時間から任意の時間までの残り時間を出力するプログラム

Tags: ios, swift

Swift で今の時間から任意の時間までの残り時間を出力してくれるプログラムを書いてます。

現在のコードでは現時刻から一秒ごとに時間が減っていくだけなので、解決策を探してます。

個人的にはcntについての定義付けがなされていないかと考えています。

何卒ご指導願います

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var cnt : Int = 0
    var timer : NSTimer!//NSTimerというデフォルト機能から引っ張る
    var myInt:Int = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        let myDate: NSDate = NSDate()
        let myCalendar: NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
        let myComponents = myCalendar.components([.Year, .Hour, .Minute, .Second],
            fromDate: myDate) // myDate、すなわちNSDateから要素として引っ張り出してる

        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "onUpdate:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)//カウントダウンのインターバル
        timer.fire()

        var myStr: String = "\(myComponents.hour)"
        myStr += "\(myComponents.minute)"
        myStr += "\(myComponents.second)"

        myInt = Int(myStr)! // toInt()がSwift2より無効になったようです。myInt=Str(my components,hour,minute,second)=現時刻

    }

    func onUpdate(timer : NSTimer){
        cnt += 1//cnt+1=cnt,
        let count = myInt - cnt //残り時間＝現在時刻ー現在時刻に１時間足した時刻
        print(count) // println()は、Swift2よりDeprecatedになりました。
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**:コメントに合わせて修正。

「バスの時刻表アプリのような」とのことですので、そのようなモチーフにしてみました。

大まかな方法は変わりません。

- 時刻をインスタンス変数に保持しておき、それを`NSDate`に変換する

  - `NSCalendar`を用いて`12:00:00`のような文字列から、当日の当該時間の`NSDate`を生成しています
  - この部分は実際的にはインスタンス変数に定数として埋め込むのではなく、ファイルやネットワークからの取得になるのだと思います
  - ここでは簡単のために（名前, 時間）のタプルの配列にしています。配列の`index`を変更するようなUIを作れば、カウントダウン対象の時間を切り替えられます
- `onUpdate()`のタイミングで毎回`NSDate()`から現在時刻を取得し、対象時間との差分を取る

  - 開始時間からの差分は`timeIntervalSinceDate()`メソッドで取得できます
  - 取得できるのは秒数なので、ここでは除算と剰余で時分秒にしています（算数の問題なので割愛）

出力例

> 午後 6時発までの時間は 03:58:46

---

**コード例**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    /** カウントダウンしたい時刻の配列 */
    private var targetDates : [(name: String, timeString: String)] = [
        ("午前11時発" , "11:15:00"),
        ("午後 3時発" , "15:30:00"),
        ("午後 6時発" , "18:45:00")
    ]

    /** タイマー */
    private var timer :NSTimer!
    /** カウントダウンの対象 */
    private var target :(name: String, time: NSDate)?

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        // 対象とする日付をセット
        let index = 2
        if let date = dateFromString(targetDates[index].timeString) {
            self.target = (targetDates[index].name, date)
        }

        // インターバル1秒でタイマーを生成
        self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1,
            target: self,
            selector: "onUpdate:",
            userInfo: nil,
            repeats: true)
        self.timer.fire()
    }

    /**
     * "HH:mm:ss"を日付型に変換
     */
    func dateFromString(dateString :String) -> NSDate? {
        let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
        calendar.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "JST")!

        let begin = dateString.startIndex
        guard let hour = Int(dateString.substringWithRange(begin..<advance(begin, 2))),
            let minute = Int(dateString.substringWithRange(advance(begin, 3)..<advance(begin, 5))),
            let second = Int(dateString.substringWithRange(advance(begin, 6)..<advance(begin, 8))) else{
                return nil
        }

        return calendar.dateBySettingHour(hour, minute: minute, second: second, ofDate: NSDate(), options: [])
    }

    func onUpdate(timer : NSTimer) {
        guard self.target != nil else {
            timer.invalidate()
            return
        }

        var remain = Int(self.target!.time.timeIntervalSinceDate(NSDate()))
        if remain < 0 {
            timer.invalidate()
            return
        }
        // 残り時間を(HH:)mm:ddで出力
        print(self.target!.name + "までの時間は ", appendNewline: false)
        if (remain >= 3600) {
            print(String(format: "%02d", arguments: [remain/3600]) + ":", appendNewline: false)
            remain %= 3600
        }
        print(String(format: "%02d:%02d", arguments: [remain/60, remain%60]))
    }
}
```

Comment: 説明不足で申し訳ないのですが、あくまで、一時間というのは仮定しているだけで、実際は指定した時刻に対して自由に現在時刻からカウントダウンしてくれるアプリという事を考えていました、簡単に言えば、よくあるバスの時刻表アプリのようなカウントダウンのシステムです、もしよければその前提でなにか補足の解決と説明をいただけますでしょうか

Comment: @yanamstyle カウントダウンする方法自体については解説が必要なく、「現時刻ではなく任意の時刻からカウントダウンしたいが、任意の時刻を受け付ける方法が分からない」ということでしょうか？

Comment: はい、おそらく、そういうことになると思われます、おそらく、辞書配列でデータから要素を呼び出す形になります。